# CF8 SSL Connection to Postgres fails

Tags: java, postgresql, coldfusion, ssl-certificate, keystore

I'm attempting an SSL connection from a ColdFusion 8 Enterprise client to a Redhat 5 Postgres server.  Another party set up Postgres and sent me the certificates.

1. I imported *root.crt* into *E:\JRun4\jre\lib\security\cacerts* successfully and restarted the service.
2. The Postgres pg_hba.conf file has the client IP, and connects fine without SSL
3. Postgresql.conf has *ssl=on*
4. The server-side certs were created according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ssl-tcp.html and presumingly done correct.

With SSL enabled, I get **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.** which produces little helpful information from the searches I've done.

JDBC URL: jdbc:postgresql://x.x.x.x/main?ssl=true
Class: org.postgresql.Driver

What can be done to see/test if the error source is on my end or the server end?

Comment: Probably OT (but who knows): Why are you reading the docs for the next, yet unreleased version of Postgres?

Comment: That is a good question, but the content is basically the same as on http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ssl-tcp.html.  However, I will modify the link.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious questions to start with in troubleshooting something like this are:

1. Can you connect with SSL enabled using psql?
2. Is there anything of interest in the postgresql logs?
3. If that doesn't work, is there a way you can test the certificate against the root ca's signature?
4. If that fails, the only thing I can think of is tracing the client side and seeing exactly where in the SSL libraries it fails.

Comment: You certainly deserve props for looking for long-forgotten problems. I resolved this awhile ago, but I'll try to dig up my notes on how I did it and post them here.

Answer (score 2):

For certificate problems add `&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` to your jdbc url. See https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl-client.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the notes I took for solving this. Note that the drive and folder paths may be different for your setup.

1. Copy server.crt.der your destination server
2. Open a command window in your destination server and go to E:\Jrun4\jre\bin\
3. Type in the following command: `keytool -importcert -alias postgres -keystore e:\jrun4\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file c:\location\of\server.crt -storepass changeit`
4. It will prompt you whether you should trust this certificate; answer yes
5. To verify it successfully installed, type: `keytool -list -alias postgres -keystore e:\jrun4\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit`. If successful you'll see a single listing return by that alias, otherwise it will say none found
6. After the certificate has been stored you may delete the actual certificate file from the server
7. Restart ColdFusion services on the client machine